# HttpWebRequest using the Async Methods - Clarification required

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm quite familiar with using the APM with classes that support the APM. However the HttpWebRequest class has a nuance that I've not noticed in any other class. And to add to the confusion, anytime I see code that uses the HttpWebRequest in an asynchronous manner it skips over the question that I have.

So here goes: When doing a POST using the HttpWebRequest class there are essentially two methods that need to be called asynchronously.

1. BeginGetRequestStream/EndGetRequestStream
2. BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse

Most of the code I see skips over calling the first and only calls the second. Examples of using Tasks and the Task.Factory.FromAsync method also "conveniently" skip over this.

I know that the connection is being established when the BeginGetRequestStream method is called. Which is I/O bound and takes a certain amount of time.

So my questions are: If one was interested in doing this the right way:

1. Shouldn't one call the Begin/End GetRequestStream methods and then call the BeginGetResponse also?
2. Using Task.Factory.FromAsync, is there an easy way to call both these methods? Other than FromAsync, then continue with and to another FromAsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way (when doing a post) is to call both those asycn methods. The reason is (as you've mentioned kind of), the calling the EndGetRequestStream (and not the BeginGetRequestStream) establishes the connection, this could take a while and so if you don't use this pair of methods then your main threads will block for that period. So if performance is key in your case then you should call both async methods.

As regards using Tasks. I don't know what you'd call "easy" but I have a blog post that goes into the performance of various styles of making http posts including some options where tasks are used as well.
[HttpWebRequest - Asynchronous Programming Model/Task.Factory.FromAsyc](http://www.matlus.com/httpwebrequest-asynchronous-programming/)

In particular in the first code listing the method PostAsyncTask is the one you're looking for. In various performance tests I've conducted I found the non Task version (the method called PostAsync) to perform slightly better. Personally I don't find (in this case the Task version simplifies anything either.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the link. Great article by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Calling Begin/End GetRequestStream is only necessary for writing to the body of your request. If you're not sending a body (ie. a GET), you can skip it.

I'm not aware of a direct way to follow a task with another task without continuewith.[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660760/how-do-i-chain-asynchronous-operations-with-the-task-parallel-library-in-net-4) shows a possible way to chain tasks. You could write an extension method with a similar style.

Comment: I specifically mentioned, "When doing a POST using the HttpWebRequest..."

Comment: Your first point is correct then. You need to to do Begin/End GetRequestStream and then Begin/EndGetResponse.